# How to use strike on text Vuejs?

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js

i'm building a todo app using vuejs and i want to make text rendered in html line through or strike() when i check on the element
here is my code:

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app">
      <h2 class="title">What should I do today?</h2>
      <div v-for="task in tasks">
        <input  type="checkbox" value=task.task v-on:change="checkedOrNot(task)">
        <span class="title" >{{task.task}}</span>
      </div>
          <new-task  @new_task_entered="handle_new_task" ></new-task>

    </div>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to do, for example, something like this:

```
<div v-for="task in tasks">
    <input  type="checkbox" value=task.task v-on:change="checkedOrNot(task)">
    <strike v-if="checkedOrNot(task)">{{task.task}}</strike>
    <span v-else class="title" >{{task.task}}</span>
<div/>
```